# System Center Configuration Manager Unable to Find Users or Devices in Domain

Tags: sccm

I've tried changing everything I can think of to get sccm to find devices and users on my domain. I even tried giving the discovery methods an account with domain admin credentials. I've setup user groups, device groups, as well as boundaries. I do not see the ad logs in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\Logs either. I'm not sure how I should proceed to get my devices and users into sccm.

SCCM Version 1902
Console Version 5.1902.1085.1700
Site Version 5.0

Windows Server 2019 Standard

Comment: I assume you've used Active Directory discovery? If not, give this a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/core/servers/deploy/configure/about-discovery-methods

Comment: Yes and I've read that but there is no adsysdis.log in this directory -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\Logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my logs to microsoft forums it was recommended I reinstall windows and sccm from scratch. This time I did it in the modular way instead of a single primary with a Central Administration Site controlling the Primary Site like recommended and everything seems to work!